# How good is the PSNR value for face region encryption?

Tags: image-processing, face-recognition, steganography

I'm working on face region encryption. The task is to detect the face, encrypt the face region and embed the coordinates of face in the image. 
Now I have three different images,

image1 - is the original image,

image2 - is the image with face region encryption,

image3 - is the image with face region encryption with coordinates embed in the image using LSB technique.

Now I have calculated PSNR value between image3 and image1.

As per theory, high PSNR value indicates lower variation between images ; this result suits for steganography only. But for encryption, the PSNR value is expected to be low to indicate high variation between the images.

But in my case, I have used both encryption and steganography  and I got the value of 18.4134. I want to know how good this value is?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programmatically related question, but a statistics one. It's also possibly opinionated without defining what would constitute a good value.

Comment: For what it's worth, a few papers I've read state that a PSNR value of 30 or above is sufficient to make any variations imperceptible to the human eye, so 18 strikes me as very low.

Comment: yea first you are voting then you continuing adding to it

Comment: @gpasch It's not an answer, just a comment. But if you don't agree with it, you have the power to flag it. I posted it just in case it guides the OP to the right direction since I doubt he'll get anything else out of this question.